# Implementing One Object, Two Kinds of Purposes

Tags: java, oop

This is something that I was wondering how to do, but could not find a way that suits the problem.

Suppose I have a class that could serve two purposes: Upload and Download. Instinctively, I would create an object somewhat like this:

```
public class File{
 private FormFile uploadFile;
 private File downloadFile;
 private String uploadLocation;
 private String downloadLocation;

 //setters and getters
}
```

The thing is, I would want to have only one set of accessors for each type. For example, there is only one `setFile(Object obj)` in the class. But this would cause a problem because FormFile and File are two distinct objects.

I would then resort for OOP. Change my object to:

```
public interface File{
 public void setFile(Object obj);
 public Object getFile();
 public void setLocation;
 public String getLocation;
}
```

Then create the two other objects:

```
public UploadFile implements File{
 private FormFile file;
 private String location;

 //implementation of methods
}

public Download implements File{
 private File file;
 private String location;

 //implementation of methods
}
```

This could work if you clean other things within the code. But I realized that this would be harder to maintain afterwards. Is there another workaround to do this?

Something **like**:

```
File file = new File.UPLOAD;
```

would restrict the user to:

Use only method `setFile(FileForm file){ }`, and then `setFile(File file){ }` would become unavailable. Works vice versa when instantiating `File file = new File.DOWNLOAD`

I'm not really trying to solve anything on this. Just a thought.

Comment: Actually that's not a good design choice. _One responsibility per Class_. So your choice to seperate into Download and Upload class is good. I cannot see, why this should be harder to maintain?

Comment: Why not define a class that extends File and then make it so that the constructor of the class will get an argument if it is upload or download? But pretty much what @Fildor says is right!

Comment: Take a look at the [Cohesion page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). One "module" (in this case, one class) should have only one responsibility. Your issues will only extend into the rest of your application, since then things that use `File` will have to check what type it is, forcing conditionals everywhere it's used since things may react differently based on its type, and it will result in very complex and redundant code. Separation of concerns creates a more cohesive model.

Comment: @Fildor What if it was for the purpose of code reuse? Can this be overruled?

Comment: The problem arises from your design.  "Upload" and "Download" are really very different things.  Because you are trying to combine two not-really-compatible actions together, the result doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: You could create static, package-private, helper classes that will allow the implementations to share code. There's always ways to refactor code like this.

Comment: @Fildor Suppose that I decide to create another set of variables, I would need to add them to the other 2 objects as well.

Comment: @Russell In this case I cannot see, why code reuse should be an argument for combining "upload" and "download" functionality in one class as described above. You can reuse two separate classes as well. Or do you mean _they_ share code?

Comment: @dan1111 I understand that, from your view they share different purposes. But they share fields in common too. Like filename, fileLocation, fileSize. That's why I had the thought that they could be in one object.

Comment: Ok, they use the same set of data. But you still will do only one thing, right? Upload _or_ download? And you could create a common abstract class to derive from that holds common fields ...

Comment: @Fildor Yes. They would still have one purpose for each file. I think I saw your point. A little bold for **one** on your comment and I could have seen it sooner. But all of the problems might not be something similar like the sample I gave. One of the answers below is something. **Generics**. Haven't tried that one yet. I'll try that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with generics:

```
public class File < T > {

    private T file;
    private String location;

    public T getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile( T file ) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation( String location ) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
File< FormFile > uploadFile = new File< FormFile >();
uploadFile.setFile( new FormFile() );

File< java.io.File > downloadFile = new File< java.io.File >();
downloadFile.setFile( new java.io.File( "something.txt" ) );
```

Comment: this seems solved OP's problem. however, how do you implement the business logic methods (upload/download) ? you have to explicitly check the type anyway.

Comment: I agree. This is just so he doesn't have to create 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-thinking it.

Just add these two methods:

```
public void setUploadFile(FormFile f);

public void setDownloadFile(File f);
```

Comment: Yes. But I was thinking that if an UPLOAD type of the FILE is instantiated, the `setDownloadFile(File f)` would be unavailable.

Comment: How will the `setDownloadFile(File f)` become unavailable ? What do you mean with "an UPLOAD type of the FILE" ?

Answer (score 0):

**-** `Interface` are used mainly with the purpose of **providing Roles**, or to **represent behaviours that keep changing**, but as Upload and Download are two different things, i dont think interface will be appropriate here.

**-** Try something like this...

**File Class :**

```
class File{

private String fileName;
private String fileLocation;

public File(String fileName, String fileLocation){

  this.fileName = fileName;
  this.fileLocation = fileLocation;

}
        //Getters for the above Field

public boolean setDownload(File f){

     new Download(f);   // Composition

 }

public boolean setUpload(File f){

      new Upload(f);   // Composition

 }
}
```

**DownLoad Class:**

```
class Download{

private String fromDestination;

// Getter and Setter for above field

public boolean dowload(File f){


   return false;  // set to true if successful
 }

}
```

**Upload Class:**

```
class Upload{

private String toDestination;

// Getter and Setter for above field

public boolean upload(File f){


    return false;  // set to true if successful
 }

}
```

Well you can use `Apache's commons` library for **File upload and File download**....